Shopify Checkout extensibility : Adding notes to order in checkout ui extension
I'm a young Shopify developer, and I'm trying to create a Shopify checkout extension where the text the user added should be added to the order note as well.
import {
  reactExtension,
  TextField,
} from '@shopify/ui-extensions-react/checkout';

export default reactExtension(
  'purchase.checkout.block.render',
  () => <Extension />,
);

function Extension() {
  return <TextField name="checkout[note]" id="checkout_note" label="PO # / Note" />;
}

Could you please help me figure this out?
Also, please suggest how I could use useNote()

Did it throw an error when you tried this?  Post that error in text form to the question if that is the case.  But you can also read the official Shopify site for all the features and commands you are questions about.

no error shown but value was not getting added to orders note in admin side , im confused how to use use useNote() , checked shopify docs but they haven't mentioned how to use it

From what I found, UseNote() isn't part of shopify?  Perhaps you had an add on that is using that?  That is where you need to research.
